# non-invertible matrix if sum of all elements in rows equals to zero

Tags: matrices

How can I prove that A is non-invertible nxn matrix if sum of all elements in rows of A equal to zero?

$$a_{11} + a_{12} + \cdots + a_{1n} = 0$$

$$a_{21} + a_{22} + \cdots + a_{2n} = 0$$

$$\vdots$$

$$a_{n1} + a_{n2} + \cdots + a_{nn} = 0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=\left(C_{1},\ldots,C_{n}\right)$
  where $C_{j}$
  is the $j$ -th column of $A$
 . Then your condition is $C_{1}+\ldots+C_{n}=0$
  that is $C_{n}=-\left(C_{1}+\ldots+C_{n-1}\right)$
  i.e. the columns of $A$
  are linearly dependant. Thus the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $A\cdot X = 0=A\cdot 0$ has a non-zero solution, namely $X = (1,1,..,1)$. This shows that the property that: " $AB = AC \Rightarrow B = C$" fails, thus $A$ is not invertible.